# 'express' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I did `npm install -g express` and still for some reason getting this error. Is anyone having the same issue?

Comment: code that throws the error?

Comment: How are you trying to use/invoke express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that express now wants you to use express-generator. So instead of `npm install -g express` it is `npm install -g express-generator`.

Answer (score 0):

run this:

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

In express(version 4), command line tool isn't bundled together, so the express command won't be recognized until you install the express generator.

Comment: Yea.. But Windows Os was mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I solved this similar issue by adding NPM global modules to my path variable.

Try add C:\Users<youruser>\AppData\Roaming\npm to your path.